# jquery 1.9 live() to on() on objects

Tags: jquery

how do I change function like this to support new jquery 1.9?

```
$.fn.message = function (options) {
    var $obj = this;
    var customErrorMsg = 'Error occurred. Please try again or contact administrator';
    var opts = $.extend({ customErrorMsg: customErrorMsg }, options);
    handleAjaxMessages(this,opts);
    $obj.live('click',function () {
        $obj.fadeOut(500, function () {
            $obj.empty();
        });
    });
};
```

specifically **$obj.live() line => on()**

Comment: You asked and in the end you answered :)

Comment: What about reading .on() method jquery documentation?

Comment: it's the same even though selector is already a jquery object?

Comment: @ShaneKm jQuery objects have a `selector` property on them that returns the string selector that created that object, so you'd do: `$(document).on('click', $obj.selector, function() {...})`. There's an answer buried on the other question (that this was closed as a duplicate of) that indicates this, but it's not explicitly stated and would be easy to miss if you didn't know exactly what to look for.

Comment: @roasted I'm reasonably sure that the documentation for `.on()` doesn't tell you how to go from a jQuery object to a string selector, which is the key to answering this question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Good catch! Didn't see it.

Comment: Voting to reopen because I don't think the answers in the "duplicate" question adequately address this particular situation.

Comment: I don't think this is possible since you don't know how `this` (the jQuery object) was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally converting from `.live()` to `.on()` is relatively simple; the exact process for doing so is documented in the [API for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

The syntax for using `.live()` has the general form `$(selector).live(event, handler)` which is slightly misleading, since it gives the impression that something vaguely wonderful happens and it just happens to know when matching elements are added to the DOM. In reality, as most people know, it's actually delegating the event handler to the document.

With that in mind, it's easy to see how it converts to the general form for `.on()` of: `$(document).on(event, selector, handler)`.

However, this conversion hinges on knowing what `selector` is. If, as in the example in the question, you were taking an arbitrary jQuery object and calling `.live()` on it, how would you convert to using `.on()`?

The answer is that you need some way of determining what `selector` should be. Fortunately jQuery already does that for you, and stores it in the `selector` property of the resulting object.

So, taking our arbitrary jQuery object `$obj`, instead of doing:

```
$obj.live(event, handler);
```

We would instead do:

```
$(document).on(event, $obj.selector, handler);
```

There are some limitations to the `selector` property, mainly when chaining functions to modify the set of matched elements. Take, for example, the following code:

```
var $obj = $('#foo');
console.log($obj.selector); // #foo
console.log($obj.find('a').selector); // #foo a
console.log($obj.children('a').selector); // (an empty string)
```

Using `.find()` correctly updates the selector. However, using `.children()` doesn't and instead removes it entirely (why doesn't this give `#foo > a`...?).

So, for "simple" jQuery objects (i.e. those constructed only using a selector), the above approach would work.

If you don't know the selector then you could probably try to simulate the event delegation yourself:

```
$(document).on(event, function(event) {
    if($obj.filter($(event.target).parents().andSelf()).length) {
        // do your actions here
    }
});
```

That essentially checks if the initial target of the event, or any of its ancestors, are inside your `$obj` jQuery object's set of matched elements, and only performs whatever the action is if that's the case.

*Note: The existence of the `selector` property is probably documented somewhere in the API, but I can't recall ever seeing it.*

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/selector/ and http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#selector-property-on-jquery-objects regarding more info about `.selector`. It especially says *"In 1.9, jQuery no longer attempts to maintain this property in chained methods, since the use of chained methods was never supported with `.live()`. Do not use the `.selector` property on a jQuery object."* and *"[...] is only maintained in jQuery 1.9 to the extent needed for supporting `.live()` in the jQuery Migrate plugin. It may be removed without notice in a future version."*

Comment: And: *"Plugins that need to use a selector should have the caller pass in the selector as part of the plugin's arguments during initialization."*.